Pasar a siguiente pantalla con un button android studio
Estoy usando la plantilla de android Botton Navigation Views Activity

Dentro de la vista de Home, puse un button con id: btnSiguienteD
la intencion de este, es que al presionar, vaya a una siguiente pantalla
para eso, cree otra carpeta que se llama durante_servicio con su archivo .java y tambien cree su archivo xml
he intentado varias maneras, pero al momento de presionar el button la APP se cierra.
Este es el codigo de Home y es donde deberia de ir esa accion de cambio de pantalla
HomeFragment.java:
package com.example.app_servicio_reporte.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.example.app_servicio_reporte.R;
import com.example.app_servicio_reporte.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    Button btn;
    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}


Hola. Considera [edit] la pregunta para agregar el mensaje de error que podrás encontrar al activar una opción llamada Logcat que suele estar en la barra inferior de Android Studio. Dinos tambien si para navegar entre destinos usas el Componente de Navegación y si definiste el destino al que quieres navegar. Y si me permites un consejo, si estás empezando una nueva App considera partir desde Jetpack Compose. Simplifica bastante el trabajo y es el futuro al que apunta Android.

Para navegar a la siguiente pantalla cuando se pulsa el botón, necesitas añadir un OnClickListener al botón y utilizar la clase Navigation para navegar al siguiente fragmento:
En primer lugar, necesitas obtener una referencia al botón en tu método onCreateView:
btn = binding.btnNextD;

Después, añade un OnClickListener al botón:
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_duringServiceFragment);
}});

En el método onClick, R.id.action_homeFragment_to_duringServiceFragment debe ser el id de la acción que navega desde el HomeFragment al DuringServiceFragment. Necesitas definir esta acción en tu gráfico de navegación.
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
        new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
View root = binding.getRoot();

btn = binding.btnNextD;
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_duringServiceFragment);
    }
});

return root;}

Asegúrate de que has definido la acción de navegación en tu gráfico de navegación. Si no lo has hecho, puedes hacerlo abriendo el archivo del gráfico de navegación, haciendo clic en HomeFragment y arrastrando y soltando una acción en DuringServiceFragment. Ya después, puedes asignar un id a esta acción
